# Dynamically created elements' event handler

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, event-handling, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 7.1 (7.5) app.
The idea: app gets an list of data from server, creates a TextBlock for each of them and applies Tap event handler for each of them.
The problem: since I can only use one handler for all of the elements, how to identify the sender?

The part for creating a new TextBlock: (note: itemsAdded is an outside variable, that is to set proper margins)

```
void addInfoItem(string text)
    {
        Thickness tempThick = fatherText.Margin;
        tempThick.Top += itemsAdded * 58;
        itemsAdded++;
        TextBlock temp = new TextBlock() { Text = text, FontSize = 40, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top, Margin = tempThick };
        temp.Tap += whenTapped;
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(temp);
    }
```

whanTapped event handler:

```
private void whenTapped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //how to identify the sender?
    }
```

When debugging, "object sender" gives enough info to identify the sender - "Text" property of the TextBlock, but during coding, all i get from "object sender" is the following: Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString. (ToString only tells that this is generally a TextBlock, that's all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but during coding, all i get from "object sender" is the following:
>     Equals, GetHashCode,GetType, ToString.

because `Object` only supports those methods and it is the parent class of all (almost).
and parent class can contain/hold the child class memebrs but you can't access the child members  untill unless you cast them to the child type.

so you use can `sender` object but you need to cast it to your control `TextBlock` to get the required members to invoke.

```
TextBlock temp = (TextBlock) sender;
temp.Invi=okeSomething(); //now you can invoke `TextBlock` memebrs
```

Comment: thanks, works =) gonna mark as the correct answer in 10mins (says I can't yet)

Comment: @IgnasLaukineitis: it's all my privilege.